# Single Dictionary or multiple dictionaries or any other alternatives

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

This is the problem I am trying to solve :
Given as list of movies in a csv file, extract the movie name and genre and be able to return a query based on the years and the genre. Basically, Parsing a CSV input file and build an indexed data storage to allow search the data in time manner.

My Attempt:
Create a Dictionary with Key as genre and value as List of movies in that genre. This dictionary will satisfy when searched by genre. 
To get results by year, I was thinking of creating another dictionary with key as year and value as list of movies in that year. This dictionary will satisfy when searched by year.

Now, when we have really large data to be read from csv, it is wise to create multiple dictionaries for each look up criteria like what I have done? Or should I just create a single List for the csv data and based on the criteria, filter it out. This will slow down the performance. Are there any better approaches to this problem?

Also in my code before displaying the values I am sorting by MovieName. Should I sort the list and save in the dictionary itself?

Any feedback related to the code is also appreciated.

CSV file source : https://gist.github.com/tiangechen/b68782efa49a16edaf07dc2cdaa855ea

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Enter Genre");
       string genre = Console.ReadLine();
       CSVReader csv = new CSVReader(@"C:\Users\Downloads\movies.csv");
       var result = csv.ReadCSVFile();
        if (result != null)
        {
            List<MovieDetails> movieDetails;
            result.TryGetValue(genre.ToUpper(), out movieDetails);
            if (movieDetails != null)
            {
                movieDetails.Sort((x, y)=> x.MovieName.CompareTo(y.MovieName));
                foreach (var item in movieDetails)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.MovieName +" "+item.Genre);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}



public class CSVReader
{
    public string filePath { get; set; }

    public CSVReader(string filepath)
    {
        this.filePath = filepath;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, List<MovieDetails>> ReadCSVFile()
    {
        try
        {
            string Line;
            Dictionary<string, List<MovieDetails>> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<MovieDetails>>();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
            {
                using (StreamReader sdr = new StreamReader(filePath))
                {
                    Line = sdr.ReadLine();
                    while ((Line = sdr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        List<MovieDetails> movieDetailsList;
                        string[] input = Line.Split(',');
                        MovieDetails movieDetails = new MovieDetails()
                        {
                            MovieName = input[0],
                            Genre = input[1].ToUpper(),
                            LeadStudio = input[2],
                            Audience = int.Parse(input[3]),
                            Profitability = float.Parse(input[4]),
                            RottenTomatoesPercent = int.Parse(input[5]),
                            WorldwideGross = decimal.Parse(input[6], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency),
                            Year = int.Parse(input[7])
                        };

                        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(movieDetails.Genre, out movieDetailsList))
                        {
                            movieDetailsList.Add(movieDetails);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dictionary.Add(movieDetails.Genre, new List<MovieDetails>() { movieDetails });
                        }

                    }

                    return dictionary;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
}



public class MovieDetails
{
    public string MovieName { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public string LeadStudio { get; set; }
    public int Audience { get; set; }
    public float Profitability { get; set; }
    public int RottenTomatoesPercent { get; set; }
    public decimal WorldwideGross { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The question is how large are your keys - it is the keys that are duplicated by a `Dictionary` and so having multiple will create multiple copies of those keys e.g. in your example you will have two copies of genre and two copies of year in memory. Year is pretty minimal - what data type is genre? Could you use an `enum` or perhaps consider `String.Intern` to create only one copy of each genre?

Comment: Genre datatype is string. Please the csv file : gist.github.com/tiangechen/b68782efa49a16edaf07dc2cdaa855ea

Also, how do I have two copies of genre in memory? Can you please explain.I just have one dictionary with key as genre and another dictionary with key as year.

Comment: Note that objects stored in two dictionaries only need to exist once in memory. I created a copy of `Dictionary` that used a `Func` on the value instead of storing a copy of the key, but it was half the speed for lookup as `Dictionary`, and I'm not sure the memory savings were worth it. Using interned `String`s should get most of the benefit.

Comment: Presumably you read the csv into a class, the class has a (`string`) field/property containing genre. The `Dictionary` that uses genre as its key will also keep a copy (ps `ToLookup` creates the equivalent of a `Dictionary<string,List<TValue>>` structure) of the key, which may not be the same memory depending on how you create the `Dictionary`. Also, unless you intern, or do something else to deliberately share the `string`s, your in-memory copy of the CSV will have separate copies of the genres.

Comment: When you say "be able to return a query based on the years and the genre" I assume you mean "be able to return an answer for a query based on the years and the genre". Did you mean it is possible to have a single query with both years and genre in it? Is it possible to have multiple years in a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Index selectivity* (the ratio of the average number of records in each "bucket" to the total number of records) is key to designing your program efficiently.

In your sample CSV genre has poor selectivity, because more than half of all movies in the sample are comedies; you would be better off walking the entire list under the circumstances. Same goes for the year: with only four distinct years available, you would be returning a quarter of all records in every search, so you might as well walk the list.

You can get better selectivity by introducing a composite index, i.e. an index with keys combining two or more columns (say, genre + year). This index has better selectivity: you would be placing ten or fewer movies in each "bucket", so when the query asks for a combination, you'd go for an index.

Note that another possibility to run queries faster is to keep your records in sorted order on one of the search keys. This would let you handle queries with a binary search and a forward scan, rather than a full scan of the data. Picking the sort column requires statistics on your search queries, because it may negatively impact queries that are based on other columns.

Comment: Are you sure chopping the (potentially very large) csv in half isn't worthwhile anyway? Without interning, walking the list with string comparisons would be much less efficient than the hash comparison... Same for year - a four times speedup would seem worth the memory for an `int`?

Comment: @NetMage comparing "rock" to "soul" is just comparing two Int16... may be even faster than Int32 :) ... Indeed if strings have long identical prefixes it would be major problem... but that for OP to try and measure.

Comment: @NetMage All this depends on how "large" is your very large file. USA produces about 700 movies per year on the average, so a file with every US movie produced to date would have under 90,000 rows. This is not much at all. Considering that once the movie record is found, you would need to do something about it (say, print it to the screen or store it in a file) the I/O operation would take ages in comparison to searching through the entire set.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Running the tests: For false, `String.==` is 3.8ms, `String.Equals` is 4.8ms, `Int16` is 0.27ms, Int32 is 0.3ms. For `String.Intern`, for true or false, `==` and `Equals` about 1.7ms, using `object` cast, `Object.==` is 0.27ms for true or false. So the only time `String` equality is comparable to `Int16`|`Int32` equality is when you use `String.Intern` and force a reference comparison by casting to `object`. This is all for 1,000,000 tests.

Comment: True, but I don't like it :) The memory cost for using some dictionaries will also be trivial and guarantee your code will scale. Of course, at some point you should be doing SQL...

Comment: @NetMage Note that the cost of the dictionary depends on selectivity as well: the higher the selectivity, the higher is the cost of the dictionary, and vice versa. As for the SQL, a lot of this analysis is applicable to your SQL database as well, when you weigh the cost of an index scan vs. a full table scan.

Comment: @NetMage string comparison strongly depends on how different strings are - different length of the strings will yield speed of just length comparison (O(1)), same length length starting with different prefix is slightly slower... the really slow once are strings that are long and differ at the end. Note that `string.GetHashCode` is O(string length) so depending on usage/strings comparing directly may be faster (small dictionary of very different long strings)... Overall there is no replacement for OP to try alternative approaches and measure...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov My testing was with your provided example strings of "rock" and "soul". Note that `Dictionary` stores all the hashcodes for entries, so only if the time to hash the query string is longer than the comparison to all the keys will `Dictionary` lose. At that point using `Intern` and reference comparison would be much faster than string comparison.

Comment: @NetMage yes... all I'm trying to point out is string comparison is not an awfully slow operation. Unless this is purely for entertainment ("education") purposes OP needs to measure whole operations and decide if extra complexity of building and maintaining indexes worth it... But building indexes is fun - so if there is no real purpose behind the task then multiple dictionaries or suffix tree all good and fun. :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, building indexes is fun. It is why I made a lookup class for indexing into collections without using any key storage, but it was half the speed of a `Dictionary`. Maybe I should look into using `Expression` trees to compile a type specific lookup method to raise speed to match `Dictionary` :)